# Voice Control for Android 2.1

Tags: bluetooth, voice-command, samsung-captivate, speakerphone

I have a Bluetooth speakerphone for my car (BlueAnt). It uses a phone's built in voice control. When I try to use it, it says that voice control is not supported by my phone (AT&T Samsung Captivate, Android 2.1). Is there a way I can get voice control (over Bluetooth) on my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that feature was added with Android 2.2 as my Moto Droid recently got the ability to do that.  Unfortunately, I believe you are out of luck until AT&T pushes an update to your phone, unless you are willing to install a non-standard ROM.

Comment: I don't think there is a Froyo ROM available. I was hoping for a work-a-round. Oh well, thanks!